# Has ellipsis occurred here?

Tags: ellipsis, coordination

When I am using Java language. I need to look up some material in its official website: [The sentence I copy from here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) The author of this document give an definition of Java Class File:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

I feel confused with the above sentence. Does the author means "file" and "directory pathnames" or "file pathnames" and "directory pathnames"? On other words, Is there an ellipsed "pathnames" after "file"?

Comment: Just like "chicken and pork recipes", "car and truck tires"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means "file pathnames and directory pathnames." Otherwise the definition would grammatically require a plural: "files and directory pathnames."